# F1-Visa application: Changing university after submission of application

Tags: usa, student-visa

I am in the process of obtaining an F1 student visa for the US. Here is my situation:

1. I submitted my DS160 (On 23 November 2017)
2. Scheduled an appointment (For 20 December 2017)
3. Payed the SEVIS fee for Univ-1

After contemplating, I decided to choose a different university Univ-2 over Univ-1. So how should I handle this in terms of visa? I see it as two processes:

1. Amending my application to have new university details and update/re-schedule my appointment.
2. Pay a new SEVIS fee for Univ-2

Can someone help me with process for the above mentioned? Also, a few more questions:

1. Should I do anything additional to have my SEVIS records deleted for Univ-1?
2. What should I do with the I20 of the University that I'm not attending?

Any help is highly appreciated. I don't want to take shortcuts, and would prefer an officially approved process to do this.

Comment: You should have asked at your interview what the proper process was. You might have to take at least one semester at the old school before switching but in any case the immigration official who interviewed you would know best. Come back here and add an answer when you find out!